# Populating the json contents in a table in JSP

Tags: java, html, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSON response object which looks like

```
{"code":code1,"items":{"id1":{"type":1,"quantity":"1"},"id2":{"type":2,"quantity":"2"}}}
```

I want to create a table in JSP which shows the contents of the items from JSON.
[The size of items json array is not fixed, it can vary]

eg: The table should look like.

T Q

1         1

2         2

What is the best way of doing this in Java??

Comment: do all of the records in your JSON array contain the same fields?

Comment: yes it contains the same.

Comment: What is the soure/destination from this response? Is it from your backend? This might be a not unnecessary detail for findng a good solution.

Comment: I am getting the response from backend. I want to parse the response in my controller and show the information in a JSP page.

Comment: are you allowed to import libraries such as [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_1_-_Convenient_way:_Use_JSONValue) or do you have to roll your own code?